# Like/gte/lte queries with struct in GORM using postgres

Tags: postgresql, go, orm, go-gorm

I have a `User` struct like this:

```golang
type User struct {
    Username         string `json:"username" bson:"username"`
    AuthorizationKey string `json:"authorization_key" bson:"authorization_key"`
    IsActive         bool   `json:"is_active" bson:"is_active"`
}
```

Right now I can query for the whole `username` using

```golang
user := &User{}
if err := db.Where(&User{
    Username: username,
}).Find(&user).Error; err != nil {
    return user, err
}
```

And I use this statement for `like` query (plain query)

```golang
db.Where("username LIKE ?", fmt.Sprintf("%%%s%%", username)).Find(&users)
```

Is it possible to use `like` query for username field with struct format? How about greater than or less than?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's not possible, Struct in where condition used for equal check for field ([Ref](http://v1.gorm.io/docs/query.html#Struct-amp-Map))

```
db.Where(&User{ Username: username})
```

For `Like/gte/lte` query you have to use plain SQL inside `where()`

```
db.Where("username LIKE ?", fmt.Sprintf("%%%s%%", username)).Find(&users)
```

Reference [here](http://v1.gorm.io/docs/query.html#Plain-SQL)

Comment: I will be happy if you tell me where is I am wrong and how to improve